# Multiline TextView with line breaks wrapping

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to create a custom infocontents template for a Google Maps pin and I'm running in to some weird behavior when it comes to wrapping a multiline `TextView` which contains text with multiple line breaks when using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/OfficeImage"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
      android:scaleType="centerInside"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:maxWidth="175dp"/>
  <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/InfoWindowTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sunshine Coast"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/InfoWindowSubtitle"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:singleLine="false"
      android:textSize="10dp"
      android:text="Level 3, 2 Emporio Place\n2 Maroochy Blvd, Maroochydore QLD 4558\nPo Box 5800, Maroochydore BC QLD 4558"
      android:maxLines="10"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

As shown in the image the text after the first wrapped line is missing. If there are no wrapped lines, or the last line is a wrapped line, then all lines are perfectly shown (see image below). Does anyone know how to get this to work properly?

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: Try using `RelativeLayout` as parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Muhammad Babar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1939564/muhammad-babar) suggestion fixes the issue. I added a RelativeLayout as the parent of the LinearLayout and now all text is properly shown (see below for working code).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/OfficeImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="175dp"/>
    <TextView
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:id="@+id/InfoWindowTitle"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Sunshine Coast"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/InfoWindowSubtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="Level 3, 2 Emporio Place\n2 Maroochy Blvd, Maroochydore QLD 4558\nPo Box 5800, Maroochydore BC QLD 4558"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```